# When trying to do apt upgrade i get an error

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-updates, pop-os

pop-os 21.04 and everytime i try to do something with apt upgrade or update i get an error of this

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.2.1-2ubuntu1pop0%7e1631200248%7e21.04%7e4d5cd49_i386.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (2001:67c:1560:8008::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
```

to keep in mind that i just switched from windows after it wasn't able to bootup

Comment: ```
## See sources.list(5) for more information, especialy
# Remember that you can only use http, ftp or file URIs
# CDROMs are managed through the apt-cdrom tool.
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210726)]/ hirsute >
```
idk where to do it

Comment: Please add the output of `grep -Rn --include=\*.list ^[^\#] /etc/apt/` to your question. [you can edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/670683/edit)

Comment: @Peregrino69 it’s better to use `sudoedit` to edit root-editable files, rather than start an editor as root. Also be careful when suggesting TLS for `apt` repositories, some repos are only available over plain HTTP.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt. Funny, over the years I've never bumped into sudoedit, have to take a look at it. Anyway my comments are moot as there's a far better solution. I'm deleting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily disable this `ppa:system76/pop`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:system76/pop
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Or you can remove the system76 repo manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-pop-*.list
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: i get an error when i do it 0% [Connecting to apt.pop-os.org (52.38.47.2)]^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 359, in main

Comment: @RealSwat see my edit please.

Comment: rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/system76-pop-*.list': No such file or directory